# R Facebook API integration

Tags: r, facebook

I would like to get Facebook ad spend data into R for analysis. This is similar to data about adspend that is available from Google Analytics (metric ga:adCost).

I read about the package Rfacebook but I dont think it supports this data retrieval.

Is there any other package or way to get this data into R? I am not familiar with Java etc, so it would be a pity if this can't be done in R.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this seems to be what you are working for:
https://github.com/cardcorp/fbRads

slides and examples are here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByjOYacj5XqBWHlwWUdJcjdrSDQ/view